# external library usage --> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-theme, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I'm creating an app using support library v7 appcompat with ActionBar and fragments for using on older Android versions. Everything is working fine so far.

But when I want to use a library (in this case javassist android), my app crashes when it starts.

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity"
```

My styles.xml looks like this

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>
```

and my Manifest.xml like this

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    ... >
    ...
</application>
```

The library has no definition of any style (I deleted those definitions).

Like I wrote, my app works without that javassist library, but it crashes when I add it to build path.

When I don't use appcompat and use native ActionBar etc, it also works. But this is no solution for me.

I don't know what's going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your activity extend the AppCompatActivity? Does your Activity use a custom style defined in Manifest? Do you use a different style in v14 o v21 folders?

Answer (score 0):

Add theme attr to activity in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    ...>
</activity>
```